# "My eyebrows raised" or "my eyebrows rose"? (Passive voice)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, passive-voice, participles

> The day before, as I watched the dog soar over the fence, my jaw dropped, and my eyebrows raised as I tried to comprehend how the dog could jump so high.

My editor says "try to avoid passive voice" and also thinks this should read:

> The day before, as I watched the dog sore over the fence, my jaw **was dropped**, and my eyebrows **were raised** as I tried to comprehend how the dog could jump so high.

Are they correct?

Comment: Would avoiding the passive voice sound like: "The day before, while watching the dog soared over the fence,  I stood with a dropped jaw and raised eyebrows and tried to comprehend how it could jump so high." ??

Comment: Your original sentence didn't contain any passive.  A bit of tweaking, and it's fine:  "The day before, as I watched the dog soar over the fence, my jaw dropped, and my eyebrows rose, as I tried to comprehend how the dog could jump so high."

Comment: Get a new editor.

Comment: For what it's worth, people tend to read clauses as sequential actions, although dropped jaw and raised brows are simultaneous parts of a single facial expression.

Comment: This is where I got the reference for the use of raised versus rose. Thoughts? https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-raised-and-vs-rose/

Comment: Yes, this cannot be stressed enough: if your editor thinks that you should avoid passive voice, you must fire your editor. And if your editor thinks that *this sentence* contains passive voice, you must fire your editor out of a cannon into the Sun. They have no idea what they are talking about. They are literally talking out of their ass. I cannot be blunt enough about it. They do not understand English. At all.

Comment: I third what Karl G and RegDwight said, and add:  the sentence your editor suggested is dreadful....appalling...even neglecting the misspelling, which could be a typo.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule of thumb, the verb *raise* (past tense *raised*), usually takes a direct object. As a general rule, the verb *rise* (past tense *rose*) is usually intransitive and usually doesn't. To *rise* means *to go up*. To *raise something*, generally means to make something *else* go up.

Although I would find the OP's sentence only slightly unusual, it would read better like this:

> The day before, as I watched the dog soar over the fence, my jaw dropped, and my eyebrows **rose** as I tried to comprehend how the dog could jump so high.

The Original Poster's editor obviously keeps their *raise* and *rise* in very different compartments, which led them to believe the Original Poster was trying to do something like this:

- With my eyebrows raised and jaw dropped, I stood staring at the spectacle.

This would not be possible in the Original Poster's example because this coordination is functioning as the main clause in the sentence and must  therefore contain tensed verbs, not participles. For this reason the editor tried to turn *my eyebrows raised* into *my eyebrows were raised* etc. (They were inadvertantly trying to turn a tensed verb phrase into a tensed verb phrase because they'd mistaken it for a participle phrase.)

Anyhow, the editor has misinterpreted the Original Poster's communicative intent, and has mistaken a tensed verb for a participle. Never trust an editor who tells you to avoid the passive. Such editors don't know their elbows from their mules.

Comment: With eyebrows raised and dropped jaw, I....

Comment: @Wordster Yes, that would also work well (or be an improvement on my example). *With* and *without* take non-finite verbs/clauses.